Getting red screen when selecting item in DropdownButton wiget
I have an issue related to DropdownButtons I have in a flutter screen.
I have 6 DropdownButtons in a screen called trxn screen. This screen allows the user to enter data and save it to a Firebase document.
When I open the trxn screen it automatically scrolls to the bottom of the page. The last DropdownButton on the screen causes the screen to be red and I can't see anything else above the red.
I have commented out all of the DropdownButtons except for the first one so I can fine the issue easier. Here is the code for the active DropdownButton below.
This is basic gist of the code:
  @override
  void initState() {

    _trxnStream = _db
            .collection('company')
            .doc(ref.read(globalsNotifierProvider).companyId)
            .collection('trxns')
            .doc(ref.read(globalsNotifierProvider).currentTrxnId)
            .snapshots()
            .listen((trxnSnapshot) {

// Populate _selectedAppraiserCompany if a value exists in db
    _selectedAppraiserCompany =
              trxnSnapshot.data()?['appraiserCompanyId'] ??
                  "Select Appraiser Company";
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false, // This fixes the keyboard white space
      body: SafeArea(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          reverse: true,
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                const Text(
                  'Transaction Details',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 30,
                  ),
                ),
                const SizedBox(
                  height: 30.0,
                ),
                const Text(
                  'Select User',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 20,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                  ),
                ),

                const Row(
                  children: [
                    Text('Appraiser Company'),
                  ],
                ),
                Row(
                  children: [
                    StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
                      stream: _db.collection('appraiserCompany').snapshots(),
                      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
                        if (snapshot.connectionState ==
                            ConnectionState.waiting) {
                          return const Center(
                            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                          );
                        }
                        if (snapshot.hasError) {
                          return const Center(
                            child: Text('Error loading data'),
                          );
                        }
                        final appraiserCompanyItems =
                            <DropdownMenuItem<String>>[];
                        appraiserCompanyItems.add(
                            const DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                                value: 'Select Appraiser',
                                child: Text('Select Appraiser Company')));
                        snapshot.data!.docs.forEach((appraiserCompany) {
                          appraiserCompanyItems.add(
                            DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                              value: appraiserCompany.id,
                              child: Text(
                                  appraiserCompany['appraiserCompanyName']),
                            ),
                          );
                        });
                        if (appraiserCompanyItems.isNotEmpty) {
                          return DropdownButton<String>(  <<<<  ERROR OCCURS HERE
                            hint: const Text("Select Appraiser"),
                            value:
                                _selectedAppraiserCompany ?? 'Select Appraiser',
                            onChanged: (appraiserCompanyValue) {
                              setState(() {
                                _selectedAppraiserCompany =
                                    appraiserCompanyValue;
                              });
                              ref
                                  .read(trxnNotifierProvider.notifier)
                                  .updateAppraiserCompanyId(
                                      _selectedAppraiserCompany!);
                            },
                            items: appraiserCompanyItems,
                          );
                        } else {
                          return const SizedBox();
                        }
                      },
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),

Here is the error I am getting:
Exception has occurred.
_AssertionError ('package:flutter/src/material/dropdown.dart': Failed assertion: line 948 pos 15: 'items == null || items.isEmpty || value == null ||
              items.where((DropdownMenuItem<T> item) {
                return item.value == value;
              }).length == 1': There should be exactly one item with [DropdownButton]'s value: . 
Either zero or 2 or more [DropdownMenuItem]s were detected with the same value)

I only get the error if _selectedAppraiserCompany is empty or null. I think this error has to do with the initialization of the dropdownbutton value from the database but I don't know how to fix it.
Any help is greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Your example is lacking a lot of context with the variables, functions, packages and classes you're using (StreamProvider, Trxn) that are not in the standard Flutter library, so if there is something specific in those that may be causing issues, more disambiguation may be required. Also, the formatting there makes it tough to get a great read on what is going on (not least because it isn't syntactically correct- try to paste your code into a dart file and see what I mean...) Feel free to update your question with more context or explain more below and I'd be happy to chat further.

I cleaned up the code. It should be much more readable. Thanks

Thanks. I think after taking a peak the answer below should still work, does that not work? Does it provide a different error, or the same? Thanks

I figured it out. Where I was initializing _selectedAppraiserCompany in initState() and where I was adding the initial list entry didn't match. Once I made them match everything worked. Thanks for your help.

Glad you got it! Cheers!

You could try to ensure that there are no duplicate values in your snapshot.data!.docs forEach loop by ensuring that any DropDownMenuItem already in the list does not conflict with the value of the item you want to add. Here is the full snippet:
StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
  builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
      return const Center(
        child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
      );
    }
    if (snapshot.hasError) {
      return const Center(
        child: Text('Error loading data'),
      );
    }
    final appraiserCompanyItems = <DropdownMenuItem<String>>[];
    appraiserCompanyItems.add(const DropdownMenuItem<String>(
        value: 'Select Appraiser',
        child: Text('Select Appraiser Company')));
    snapshot.data!.docs.forEach((appraiserCompany) {
      if (appraiserCompanyItems
          .where((element) => element.value == appraiserCompany.id)
          .isEmpty) {
        appraiserCompanyItems.add(
          DropdownMenuItem<String>(
            value: appraiserCompany.id,
            child: Text(appraiserCompany['appraiserCompanyName']),
          ),
        );
      }
    });
    if (appraiserCompanyItems.isNotEmpty) {
      return DropdownButton<String>(
        hint: const Text("Select Appraiser"),
        value: _selectedAppraiserCompany ?? 'Select Appraiser',
        onChanged: (appraiserCompanyValue) {
          setState(() {
            _selectedAppraiserCompany = appraiserCompanyValue;
          });
          ref
              .read(trxnNotifierProvider.notifier)
              .updateAppraiserCompanyId(_selectedAppraiserCompany!);
        },
        items: appraiserCompanyItems,
      );
    } else {
      return const SizedBox();
    }
  },
),

Also, you might want to do this:
StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
  builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
      return const Center(
        child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
      );
    }
    if (snapshot.hasError) {
      return const Center(
        child: Text('Error loading data'),
      );
    }
    final appraiserCompanyItems = <DropdownMenuItem<String>>[];
    snapshot.data!.docs.forEach((appraiserCompany) {
      if (appraiserCompanyItems
          .where((element) => element.value == appraiserCompany.id)
          .isEmpty) {
        appraiserCompanyItems.add(
          DropdownMenuItem<String>(
            value: appraiserCompany.id,
            child: Text(appraiserCompany['appraiserCompanyName']),
          ),
        );
      }
    });
    if (appraiserCompanyItems.isNotEmpty) {
      return DropdownButton<String>(
        hint: const Text("Select Appraiser"),
        value: _selectedAppraiserCompany,
        onChanged: (appraiserCompanyValue) {
          setState(() {
            _selectedAppraiserCompany = appraiserCompanyValue;
          });
          ref
              .read(trxnNotifierProvider.notifier)
              .updateAppraiserCompanyId(_selectedAppraiserCompany!);
        },
        items: appraiserCompanyItems,
      );
    } else {
      return const SizedBox();
    }
  },
),

^ The difference here is that the _selectedAppraiserCompany value is allowed to be null, in which case instead of literally having an item that means needs-selection, it's just null and you can use the built-in fallback hint widget which you are currently already using. Up to you.
